# Como inverter caixa alta e caixa baixa dos caracteres de uma string sem usar o isupper()?

Tags: python, string

Como eu faço para saber se os caracteres de uma string são maiúsculos sem usar o [`str.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper)?

O meu código está assim, mas na parte de verificar o [caixa dos caracteres](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caixa_alta_e_caixa_baixa) eu não consigo fazer a verificação.

```
retorno = ''
for caractere in frase:
    #if caractere.isupper():
    if frase == frase.upper():
        retorno += caractere.lower()
    else:
        retorno += caractere.upper()
return retorno
```

frase

```
 'cAmInHaDa LoNgA'
```

retorno esperado

```
'CaMiNhAdA lOnGa'
```

retorno atual

```
'CAMINHADA LONGA'
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Seu `if` está fazendo a validação do elemento errado, mude `if frase == frase.upper():` para `if caractere == caractere.upper():`, creio que é o suficiente para obter o retorno esperado.

Comment: Fiz umas mudanças na sua pergunta e espero que sejam de seu agrado. Caso não concorde com as edições você pode as reverter clicando [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/540211/revisions) e restaurando alguma uma das versões. Ps: acho que deveria estar escrito *Como eu faço para saber se os caracteres de uma string são maiúsculos sem usar o str.isupper() ou str.islower()?*, mas como não estava no conteúdo original não acrescentei.

Answer (score 1):

Como dito no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/540211/como-saber-se-os-caracteres-de-uma-string-s%C3%A3o-maiusculos-phyton#comment970631_540211) do [Zé Reis M. Olliver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/131377/z%C3%A9-reis-m-olliver) se você quer inverter o caixa da frase está fazendo a validação no objeto errado, mude:

`if frase == frase.upper():`

para

`if caractere == caractere.upper():`

Exemplo corrigido:

```
frase = 'cAmInHaDa LoNgA'
retorno = ''
for caractere in frase:
    if caractere == caractere.upper():
        retorno += caractere.lower()
    else:
        retorno += caractere.upper()
print(retorno)
#CaMiNhAdA lOnGa
```

<sup>Tese o exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/Kxe3GG)</sup>

Uma alternativa interessante é utilizar o método [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) que retorna uma cópia da string na qual cada caractere foi mapeado através da tabela de tradução.
Essa tabela de tradução pode ser construída com o método estático [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) retorna uma tabela de tradução usável por `str.translate()`, um caso de uso desse método é a passagem de dois argumentos, x e y, strings de igual comprimento onde no dicionário resultante cada caractere em x será mapeado para o caractere na mesma posição em y. No caso passe duas listas combinando contrariamente entre si [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) e [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase).

```
import string
frase = 'cAmInHaDa LoNgA'

trans = str.maketrans(
  string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase,
  string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase
)

print(frase.translate(trans))
#CaMiNhAdA lOnGa
```

<sup>Tese o exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/EXGCYl)</sup>